# how to set UItextlabel text from another object

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield, nsobject

I am setting an NSString inside an NSobject in which I want to pass the value over to  uitableviewcell UIlable in a different view? I am woundering what the code would be to set this correctly as I feel like I am doing the right thing but its just not changing the text in the label..

```
//inside tableview/forRowAtIndexPath
    //load VehicleSearchObjects
    VehicleSearchObject *vehicleSearchObject = [[VehicleSearchObject alloc] init];

    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            UILabel *label1;
            label1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            label1.text = @"Manufacture";

            UILabel *label2;
            label2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
            label2.text = [vehicleSearchObject manufacturerString]; //this is where I try to set the text... but nothing is happening, am I doing it right or should I be doing something else?
```

Comment: post some more code....what does this manufacturerString do? and what thing is assigned tag 1 and 2?

Comment: tag 1 and two are defining which UIlabel is which. When you create a custom tableviewcell with labels you can set a tag value inside the interface-builder, this is just referencing that so those values are passed to the correct UILabel. manufacture string is just a string I am passing to a NSObject for later use in the parent view.. Basicly the overall goal here is for an object to hole a bunch of values that I will use to search a big database.

Answer (score 0):

If changing `label1`'s text works, then I'd look into whether or not the label you're trying to access is indeed of tag `2`, and if true, if `manufacturerString` is indeed returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `vehicleSearchObject` every time the method is called. I hope `manufacturerString` is not `nil`. Also, `UILabel` might not have memory if you do not allocate it any. Try making it a `@property`. You can check if it has memory in the debugger console.

EDIT: Declare `UILabel * label1` and write `@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel * label1;` in your interface or `.h` file and `@synthesize label1;` in your implementation or `.m` file. Alloc/init the labels in your `UIView` initializing methods like `viewDidLoad:` etc. This allocates memory to `label1` with scope across all functions. Now, do not write `UILabel *label1;` again. Just keep setting the text according to your requirements. Similarly for `label2`.

Comment: yea I think my initialization is going to cause problems but im not sure how else I can handle this.. it will need to hold several values that each get initialized separately..

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try [UILabel setText:(NSString)] instead of UILabel.text = (String).

Comment: `label.text=str;` is identical to `[label setText:string];` Also, either needs to be called on an *instance* of a `UILabel` and not on the class `UILabel`.